# Spring Integration Blocking Poller, async Downstream, flow complete signal

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to configure a poller that queries a bean to get a List into a channel every X seconds. This channel has a downstream flow which splits the list and outputs to a pub/sub channel (further async flow)
How can I make sure that at any given time only once execution of flow is in flight and poller has to wait/block until the flow completes until it is ready for the next poll (fixed rate/delay)?

```
<int:channel id="configListChannel" />
<task:executor id="pollExecutor" pool-size="1" queue-capacity="1" rejection-policy="ABORT" />
<int:inbound-channel-adapter expression="configMap().values()" auto-startup="true" channel="configListChannel">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="30" time-unit="SECONDS" task-executor="pollExecutor"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<task:executor id="configExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
<int:channel id="configChannel" >
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="configExecutor"/>
</int:channel>
<int:chain input-channel="configListChannel" output-channel="configChannel" id="configChain">
    <int:splitter/>
    <int:filter expression="payload.enablePolling"/>
</int:chain>
```

... further async flow on `configChannel` to send outbound messages

Any examples of a blocking poller with async hand off and using barrier to signal flow complete to the poller thread? Also only one poll at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to implement a `ReceiveMessageAdvice` (since 5.3 or `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice` otherwise). It's `afterReceive()` should just return the message as is, but `beforeReceive()` should check some state and return `false` if you can't poll at the moment.

You probably don't need a barrier for that task, but simple `AtomicBoolean` bean to check the state in that `beforeReceive()` to `false` and bring it back to `true` when you finish your task downstream.

Comment: In the `beforReceive()` how can I check the state which in my case is flow completion (async sqs dispatch to multiple queues), how to track all acks?.

Comment: Probably you should gather those completions in the aggregator and than change an `AtomicBoolean` to `true`.

Comment: I thought so. Also, since I don't have a splitter, I will have to use a custom MessageGroup correlation strategy. I am sending messages in a loop using gateway. and then the Gateway flow sends it to a pub/sub channel with 2 SQS endpoints for 2 different queues. Any other solution? All of this I can do using a Future and Java code, but I would like to use flows since it gives me this behaviour out of the box.

Comment: Sure! you can introduce any custom correlation strategy to combine those messages into a group.

Comment: Ended up with a Receiving Advice as suggested, refer to EDIT 2